# App with Django in Apache is not working: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, apache

First of all, I'm new on this. I explain my situation below.

I'm new on a company, and they did me a complete application written in Python with Django framework in an Apache server. This application runs fine if I execute it from the instruction runserver: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000. But this server was configured as a WSGI and worked fine weeks ago. But the app broke down and I can only execute from Python. I think the problem is the configuration of the apache server, but I get lost.

This is my virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin flopez@wtelecom.es
ServerName remote-test.teams.es

WSGIDaemonProcess remote-test.teams.es display-name=%{GROUP} user=wtelecom group=wtelecom maximum-requests=100 inactivity-timeout=300
WSGIProcessGroup remote-test.teams.es

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/wtelecom/teams/app.wsgi

Alias /media/ /home/wtelecom/teams/app/media/
<Directory /home/wtelecom/teams/media/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /videos/ /backup/
<Directory /backup/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /admin_media/ /home/wtelecom/teams/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/

<Directory /home/wtelecom/teams/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>


ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/remote-test.teams.es.error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel debug

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/remote-test.teams.es.access.log combined
```

This is my app.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import os, sys

def add_python_path():
  import sys, os
  import site
  root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  paths = (
    os.path.join(root, "app2"),
  )
  for path in paths:
      if not path in sys.path:
          sys.path.insert(0, path)

  # add virtualenv
  site.addsitedir(os.path.join(root, "env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/"))


add_python_path()
# Get rid of 'sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi' error
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

When I access to the server, a standard error 500 appears. Please, I request some help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you see in the Apache error log?

Comment: Set `DEBUG=True` in settings file and see if you get more error information.

Comment: If you are not familiar with this and there are other things running on the Apache server, I would advise you to ask someone who is familiar to troubleshoot this issue. Doing repairs on a production server when you aren't comfortable with it, is very risky.

Comment: In the Apache error log appears the same error again and again:

    [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1219197184,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored.

By the way, it seems to be solved, but I don't know how I got it. Now the application is running, but other internal problems in specific sections of the app have appeared (related with the module django_beanstalkd). I'll try to fix them and, if don't get it, I will return and post again. 

Thank you all for the help and advices.